# OpenManage keeps crashing on Server 2008 R2

Tags: windows-server-2008, dell-openmanage

Most of our servers are Dell boxes running Windows 2003 R2, and we are planning an upgrade to Server 2008 across the board.

To that end we have already upgraded one of our servers using an in-place upgrade, and everything seems to be working fine--with Windows and our applications.

But Dell's OpenManage is not working well at all. It starts fine, and runs initially, but after a few days, the services stop responding and we can no longer use it properly. Battery and power status are reported, but storage, memory, fans, temperature, and voltage monitoring stop responding.

When this happens, "DSM SA Data Manager" service cannot be restarted, and remains in "stopping" state when stopped or restarted. Killing the process via Task Manager allows it to be started, and then things are fine for another few days.

We have tried uninstalling and reinstalling, but to no effect.

This is with OpenManage 6.3.0 in Windows Server 2008 R2 x64.

Ideas?

Comment: @Nixphoe what does that even mean?

Comment: It's how the asker accepts an answer. If the answer fixed your issue, use the check mark next to it. It shows your involvement in the community beyond just asking

Comment: @Nixphoe when I get a useful answer that helps with the problem, I do. But if you check my questions you'll see most have gone unanswered or with answers that don't help the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the latets version of DOMSA is 6.5.0, 2247_A01. Available here:

http://support.dell.com/support/downloads/download.aspx?c=us&cs=19&l=en&s=dhs&releaseid=R300521&SystemID=PWE_1950&servicetag=&os=WNET&osl=en&deviceid=2331&devlib=0&typecnt=0&vercnt=12&catid=36&impid=-1&formatcnt=0&libid=36&typeid=-1&dateid=-1&formatid=-1&source=-1&fileid=451207

I would install the latest version and see if that corrects the problem.

Comment: Looks like Dell fixed something in that version; it's been running fine since Thursday, which is the longest it's gone yet.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted out.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to fix this is to contact Dell. It's their software and nobody knows the ins and outs like they would. Regardless if you have a warranty on it, they will still support their product.